# Does anyone know why my ListView behaves this way?

Tags: swift, xcode, listview, swiftui, uikit

So I'll keep it simple: I have a `ListView` inside a `Navigation View` and all I'm trying to do is get rid of the grey background area and replace it with white color. I add `color.white` to the `View` but this is what I get (basically it adds a whole white block on top):

**GUI**
[image: GUI]

**Code**
[image: Code]

All I want is to replace that grey area with white color.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my view? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Remove that Color.white (it just by default placed one ofter another) and make List plain, like

```
List {
// ... your content here
}
.listStyle(.plain)    // << here !!
```

Comment: Holy cow how do people even know these commands except me. Haha but thanks though, it worked just fine. So I'm assuming there are different "kinds" of list views and this one is just "plain"?